# Why do I keep getting the following error "NameError" and 'Attribute Error'?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

Hello I am trying to open up an h5py file, but I keep getting the following error:
*NameError: name 'h5py' is not defined*

Also I am trying to open the file up by using a Jupyter Notebook.

I had this previous code too:

```
import h5py
DataOne = 'snapshot_121.hdf5'
f = h5py.File(DataOne, 'r')
```

Comment: Seems like the import failed. Did you execute the import statement?

Answer (score 0):

Install `pip install h5py` in your virtual environment and activate the environment to access the library.